# Delphi XE5 open pdf for mobile

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi, pdf, delphi-xe5

I am using XE5 to create a mobile app and one thing I need to do is be able to download a PDF as a byte stream via a datasnap server, store it on the local device and then open it.

I have manage to download and store a PDF on the local device (not using datasnap server yet, but simply using an Indy HTTP control.  This works okay for now and the document is definitely stored on the local device.

Now I am trying to open it and am struggling to figure out how to.

This filename points to the correct file:

```
filename := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Test.pdf');
```

This points to

```
/Users/versodev/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/96674DE6-7997-48F9-9892-1383EBCE473B/Documents/Test.pdf
```

I have tried using the `Apple.Utils` class in the samples folder and using `SharedApplication.OpenURL` but this does not work (even if I convert the filename to a NSUrl).

Interestingly though, the `canOpenURL` returns `true`.

Any ideas on how I can simply open a PDF document that is stored in the Documents folder of the app on the local device?  I don't mind using a default app (eg Safari), or creating a control in my app to view it.

(I have tried using the `UIDocumentInteractionController` but am not totally sure how it works)

Comment: I would try to load it into a mobile TWebBrowser equivalent. Just an idea.

Comment: This was my question! Not sure how it ended up under someone else's name?!  See first version of my question on Embarcadero: https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=611108#611108